# Is there a way to remove the last token from the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, token, tokenize

In the index analyzer I'm tokenizing with the `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`. Generally the strings are split into two tokens, and it turns out that the remaining steps of my analyzer are better fitted to just the first token rather than both.

Is there a way to remove this second token from also being used in the remaining analyzer?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with any filter that allows you to remove arbitrary tokens (although it shouldn't be too hard to write), but you can possibly work around it by using a [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory).

If you have a common separator (i.e. a space / whitespace), you can remove anything after the separator, leaving just the first token present. This won't work if you need more advanced tokenization, but as long as you an express it as a regular expression, you should be OK.

Comment: Oh really? How can you remove anything after the separator? I'm actually strictly separating on white space.

Comment: A regular expression matching anything but whitespace and using that as the replacement key should work; try `pattern="([^ ]+) .*" replacement="$1"` and modify until you get the result you want.